# Android displaying info from database using arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I can't work out how to get the information i've managed to get to add and save to my database in the arraylist i've designed.  This button works to get the records (I've put a log trace to check this) but I can't transfer them to the list view.... I'm fairly new to android....

```
public class ActualSalesTracker extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button BtnSalesCal, BtnAddRecordDB, BtnViewRecordsDB;
    EditText item_name, item_cost, item_price_value, item_postage, actual_pl;
    SalesProfitLossCal actSalesCal = new SalesProfitLossCal();
    Cursor c;
    DbAdapter db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actual_sales_tracker);
        db = new DbAdapter(this);
        Log.d("write database", "got here");

        Button salesCalBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnSalesCal);
        // register the click event with the sales calculating profit/loss
        // button
        salesCalBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    // activate the view record button
    Button viewRecordsDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnViewRecordsDB);
    // register the click event with the add record button
    viewRecordsDB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            db.open();
            c = db.getAllRecords();
            db.close();

            Log.d("got records", "Got the records");
            Toast.makeText(ActualSalesTracker.this, "Loading saved sales",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

}

my get all records file from my database adapter

```
        public Cursor getAllRecords() {
            return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_ITEM_NAME, KEY_ITEM_COST, KEY_ITEM_PRICE_VALUE,
                    KEY_ITEM_POSTAGE, KEY_ACTUAL_PL }, null, null, null, null,
                    null, null);

        }

    /**

 * method to retrieve a particular record
 */
public Cursor getRecord(long id) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, KEY_ITEM_NAME, KEY_ITEM_COST, KEY_ITEM_PRICE_VALUE,
            KEY_ITEM_POSTAGE, KEY_ACTUAL_PL }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: post the code for `db.getAllRecords();` and please delete irrelevant code from the question. post the code only sufficient to identify your problem otherwise most will not even read the question.

Comment: Will do! Thank you for your feed back - I'm new to this and appreciate you looking into this for me.

Comment: Why use an `ArrayList` when querying a database? The query returns a `Cursor` which can be used with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate a `ListView`. There are many examples out there if you search for them.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList();

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + your table name + " WHERE " + your conditions + "\"", null);

```
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            <the type you want to get the result> offlineFile = cursorToOfflineFile(cursor);

            fileList.add(offlineFile);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

cursor.close();

return fileList;